# IndexOf and SIN

Tags: java, trigonometry

I am building a calculator but if i do not have anything to the left of "sin" i do not get an output. But if i put numbers before "sin" it will perform the operation and give me the sin of the numbers to the right. I want it to be able give you the sin of a number even if put in as.... "sin43"

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class InputScanner_operations {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str;

    System.out.println("Input your equation");

    str = input.nextLine();

    int X = str.indexOf("X");
    int x = str.indexOf("x");
    int div = str.indexOf("/");
    int plu = str.indexOf("+");
    int sub = str.indexOf("-");
    int sin = str.indexOf("s");

    int type = 0;

    if (X != -1)
        type = 1;
    else if (x != -1)
        type = 2;
    else if (div != -1)
        type = 3;
    else if (plu != -1)
        type = 4;
    else if (sub != -1)
        type = 5;
    else if (sin != -1)
        type = 6;
    else
        type = 0;

    switch (type) {

    case 1: {
        int pos = str.indexOf("X");
        for (int i = 1; i <= pos; i++) {

            String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0,
                    Math.min(str.length(), i));
            String downToNCharacters = str.substring(pos + 1,
                    Math.max(str.length(), i));

            if (i == pos) {

                Double left = Double.parseDouble(upToNCharacters);
                Double right = Double.parseDouble(downToNCharacters);
                System.out.println(left * right);
            }
        }
    }
        break;
    case 2: {
        int pos = str.indexOf("x");
        for (int i = 1; i <= pos; i++) {

            String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0,
                    Math.min(str.length(), i));
            String downToNCharacters = str.substring(pos + 1,
                    Math.max(str.length(), i));

            if (i == pos) {

                Double left = Double.parseDouble(upToNCharacters);
                Double right = Double.parseDouble(downToNCharacters);
                System.out.println(left * right);
            }
        }
    }
        break;
    case 3: {
        int pos = str.indexOf("/");
        for (int i = 1; i <= pos; i++) {

            String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0,
                    Math.min(str.length(), i));
            String downToNCharacters = str.substring(pos + 1,
                    Math.max(str.length(), i));

            if (i == pos) {

                Double left = Double.parseDouble(upToNCharacters);
                Double right = Double.parseDouble(downToNCharacters);
                System.out.println(left / right);
            }
        }
    }

        break;
    case 4: {
        int pos = str.indexOf("+");
        for (int i = 1; i <= pos; i++) {

            String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0,
                    Math.min(str.length(), i));
            String downToNCharacters = str.substring(pos + 1,
                    Math.max(str.length(), i));

            if (i == pos) {

                Double left = Double.parseDouble(upToNCharacters);
                Double right = Double.parseDouble(downToNCharacters);
                System.out.println(left + right);
            }
        }
    }
        break;
    case 5: {
        int pos = str.indexOf("-");
        for (int i = 1; i <= pos; i++) {

            String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0,
                    Math.min(str.length(), i));
            String downToNCharacters = str.substring(pos + 1,
                    Math.max(str.length(), i));

            if (i == pos) {

                Double left = Double.parseDouble(upToNCharacters);
                Double right = Double.parseDouble(downToNCharacters);
                System.out.println(left - right);
            }
        }
    }
    case 6: {
        int pos = str.indexOf("s");
        for (int i = 1; i <= pos; i++) {
            String upToNCharacters = str.substring(0,
                    Math.min(str.length(), i));
            String downToNCharacters = str.substring(pos + 3,
                    Math.max(str.length(), i));

            if (i == pos) {

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Double left = Double.parseDouble(upToNCharacters);
            Double right = Double.parseDouble(downToNCharacters);
            System.out.println(Math.sin(right));
            }
        }
    }
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Please check your formatting");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Food for thought: what should happen if you enter `sin 45 + sin 120`?

Comment: That's a lot of code for us to sift through. Where do you think the problem is? We don't want to waste time trying to understand code unrelated to the problem.

Comment: While I have sometimes questioned the ethics of `indexOf`, I stop short at calling it "SIN".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this bit of code:

```
case 6: {
    int pos = str.indexOf("s");
    for (int i = 1; i <= pos; i++) {
```

you find the index of `"s"`, and then start your `for` loop. But if the `sin` is at the beginning then `pos` will be 0, not 1, and so your `for` loop will never execute at all. Remember that a `String` is indexed from 0.

Try changing it to `int i = 0` rather than `int i = 1` in your `for` loop.